pgpool2 auto_failback doesn't attach node
I seem to be having an issue with auto_failback, pgpool detects that the node is back up but it wont reattach it.
I am running postgres 17 and pgpool2 4.5, this is config
listen_addresses = '*'
port = 5432
backend_hostname0 = '192.168.1.232'
backend_port0 = 5432
backend_weight0 = 1
backend_flag0 = 'ALLOW_TO_FAILOVER'
backend_application_name0 = 'db232'
backend_hostname1 = '192.168.1.234'
backend_port1 = 5432
backend_weight1 = 1
backend_data_directory1 = '/var/lib/postgresql/17/main/'
backend_flag1 = 'ALLOW_TO_FAILOVER'
backend_application_name1 = 'db234'
auth_type='md5'                                   # Use pool_hba.conf for client authentication
pool_passwd = '/etc/pgpool2/pool_passwd'
allow_clear_text_frontend_auth = on
process_management_mode = dynamic
process_management_strategy = gentle
num_init_children = 200
min_spare_children = 5
max_spare_children = 10
max_pool = 4
log_destination = 'stderr'
log_error_verbosity = default          # terse, default, or verbose messages
client_min_messages = debug1          # values in order of decreasing detail:
log_min_messages = debug1             # values in order of decreasing detail:
logging_collector = off
connection_cache = on
load_balance_mode = on
sr_check_user = 'custom_user'
sr_check_password = 'password'
sr_check_database = 'postgres'
health_check_period = 10
health_check_timeout = 20
health_check_user = 'user'
health_check_password = 'password'
health_check_database = 'postgres'
failover_command = '/var/lib/postgresql/test %d %h %p %D %m %H %M %P %r %R %N %S failover'
failback_command = '/var/lib/postgresql/test %d %h %p %D %m %H %M %P %r %R %N %S failback'
failover_on_backend_error = on
failover_on_backend_shutdown = on
recovery_user = 'user'
recovery_password = 'password'
recovery_timeout = 0
auto_failback = on
auto_failback_interval = 10

this is the pool nodes, when

all is up,
I stop standby server
I restart standby server

1.
 node_id |   hostname   | port | status | pg_status | lb_weight |  role   | pg_role | select_cnt | load_balance_node | replication_delay | replication_state | replication_sync_state | last_status_change
---------+--------------+------+--------+-----------+-----------+---------+---------+------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+------------------------+---------------------
 0       | 192.168.1.232 | 5432 | up     | up        | 0.500000  | primary | primary | 0          | false             | 0                 |                   |                        | 2024-11-11 19:34:10
 1       | 192.168.1.234 | 5432 | up     | up        | 0.500000  | standby | standby | 0          | true              | 58152             |                   |                        | 2024-11-11 19:34:10


2.

 node_id |   hostname   | port | status | pg_status | lb_weight |  role   | pg_role | select_cnt | load_balance_node | replication_delay | replication_state | replication_sync_state | last_status_change
---------+--------------+------+--------+-----------+-----------+---------+---------+------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+------------------------+---------------------
 0       | 192.168.1.232 | 5432 | up     | up        | 0.500000  | primary | primary | 0          | true              | 0                 |                   |                        | 2024-11-11 19:34:10
 1       | 192.168.1.234 | 5432 | down   | down      | 0.500000  | standby | unknown | 0          | false             | 0                 |                   |                        | 2024-11-11 19:38:51


3.
 node_id |   hostname   | port | status | pg_status | lb_weight |  role   | pg_role | select_cnt | load_balance_node | replication_delay | replication_state | replication_sync_state | last_status_change
---------+--------------+------+--------+-----------+-----------+---------+---------+------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+------------------------+---------------------
 0       | 192.168.1.232 | 5432 | up     | up        | 0.500000  | primary | primary | 0          | true              | 0                 |                   |                        | 2024-11-11 19:34:10
 1       | 192.168.1.234 | 5432 | down   | up        | 0.500000  | standby | standby | 0          | false             | 0                 |                   |                        | 2024-11-11 19:38:51



I see the pg_satus reflect the change but status stills stays down .
thanks guys
